# Anti-aliasing in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do I enable anti-aliasing in minecraft?

In [some wallpapers](http://www.howtogeek.com/60379/desktop-fun-minecraft-wallpaper-collection-series-1-bonus-size/) I see anti-aliasing, like in this example:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure these use *in-game* AA rather than just an edited screenshot?

Comment: I don't know. But If there is any possible way play with anti-aliasing, it will be great

Comment: That's the point, I'm fairly sure that Minecraft does not support anti-aliasing.

Comment: Ah, the irony in playing such a blocky game and wanting antialiasing.

Answer (score 10):

You can force Anti-Aliasing via the control panel of your graphicscard, but at this point Minecraft does not play nicely together with Anti-Aliasing. Graphical glitches and artifacts are appearing especially in the water and above torches.

Just compare these two screenshots, first without, second with Anti-Aliasing.

[image: Without AA]
[image: With AA]

Comment: the water is anisotropic filtering, not anti-aliasing. AA only affects edges not interior textures. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/anisotropic-filtering.html

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: I expect that Minecraft renders every water block's top as a separate polygon, so it would be affected by polygon AA.

Comment: I do not find any anti-aliasing in second image. Just look at the lower right candle, its edges are as creepy as without anti-aliasing. Though edges of grass near water looks anti-aliased

Answer (score 6):

Isn't it just a different skin? You can change skins, including using higher-definition ones.

Comment: Using a different skin has nothing to do with anti-aliasing.

Comment: @Nick: of course.

Answer (score 5):

If you have the nVIDIA drivers for Windows, you can force this setting on.

Press right mouse button on your desktop, open the Nvidia Control Panel, click Manage 3D Settings and press program settings then press "add" then press browse and search for minecraft.exe (mine's on my desktop) then:

- change anisotropic filtering to 16x
- change anti aliasing gamma correction to On
- change anti aliasing options to 16xQ
- change anti aliasing mode to Enhance the application setting
- change anti aliasing transparency to 8x Supersampling
- change triple buffering to On
- change maximum pre-rendered frames to 8
- change texture filtering anisotropic sample optimisation to On
- change texture quality to High quality
- change texture filtering trilinear optimisation to On
- change threaded optimisation to On

It made my Minecraft look really awesome, and if your computer crashes, just change all the settings back to the option with the Nvidia logo.

Comment: This is platform dependent.

Comment: @Alian but it still answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct that Minecraft has no AA support.

Unfortunately I'm at work and can't hit the Minecraft forums for the exact link, but as I recall mod that adds GLSL shaders adds an anti-aliasing setting, but with default textures I notice zero difference.  (I don't think this mod is updated for 1.5 yet.)

You also, depending on your graphics card, might be able to force AA on the application externally, but that would probably look awful.

Answer (score 1):

Another option I have not seen mentioned is using a different '3rd party' launcher that adds visual effects such as [Spout](http://www.spout.org/) or Magic Launcher.  They add tons of graphic options and features.

Answer (score 1):

Add the new ultra optifine. You can then enable AA through it in Minecraft. I believe it's under quality.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a different skin.  I think that the textures here are much cleaner than the default textures.

I don't think that the picture you found has had any AA applied;  You can't enable AA in Minecraft at the moment.

I don't know that the graphics will ever be need to have jagged edges refined :-D

Comment: Needing anti-aliasing has nothing to do with the "intensity" of the graphics, but is simply a feature to reduce moire or jagged edges.

Comment: Unless it's an artifact of not being shown at the proper resolution, that first image has definitely had anti-aliasing.  The sand/water interface provides compelling evidence, but the better evidence comes from the grass/dirt interface on the right.